# Using Isotope with AngularJS (ng-repeat)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use angular to load div's to supply to isotope for layouting.  For some reason, I can't use ng-repeat to create the div's.  When I do something like, it works fine:

[agg.html]

```html
<div class="mygrid" iso-grid>
    <div class="item">myitem</div>
</div>
```

[controlers.js]

```js
module.directive('isoGrid', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item'
        });
    };
});

module.controller('aggViewport', ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.cards = [{
        "ID": "myid",
        "class": "cardListTile",
        "badge": "1"
    } {
        "ID": "myid2",
        "class": "cardListTile",
        "badge": "2"
    }]
}]);
```

While the above works ok, when I try to use ng-repeat from angular, the div's seem to become invisible (they are in the dom, but I can't see them).  I've tried calling isotope('reloadItems') and isotope('reLayout'), but it doesn't seem to help.

[agg.html]

```html
<div class="mygrid" iso-grid ng-repeat="card in cards">
    <div class="item">myitem</div>
</div>
```

How can I use ng-repeat ?

Comment: To avoid this kind of issues I wrote a native AngularJS equivalent to jQuery isotope, feel free to take a look: http://tristanguigue.github.io/angular-dynamic-layout

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try $watching the list variable (cards), and whenever it changes re-apply the isotope.  I think your problem is isotope is running before the ng-repeat is filled in.

Quick example:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
  elm.isotope();
});
```

Comment: What is the attrs.ngModel?

Comment: It is the scope value of the ng-model attribute provided in the html. See -scope under Directive Definition Object [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 10):

I implemented something similar using a masonry directive + ng-animate for enter/leave animations, here's a CSS animation only demo (with chrome vendor prefixed CSS):

http://jsfiddle.net/g/3SH7a/

The directive:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive("masonry", function () {
    var NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE = '<!-- ngRepeat: ((.*) in ((.*?)( track by (.*))?)) -->';
    return {
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            // auto add animation to brick element
            var animation = attrs.ngAnimate || "'masonry'";
            var $brick = element.children();
            $brick.attr("ng-animate", animation);

            // generate item selector (exclude leaving items)
            var type = $brick.prop('tagName');
            var itemSelector = type+":not([class$='-leave-active'])";

            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var options = angular.extend({
                    itemSelector: itemSelector
                }, attrs.masonry);

                // try to infer model from ngRepeat
                if (!options.model) { 
                    var ngRepeatMatch = element.html().match(NGREPEAT_SOURCE_RE);
                    if (ngRepeatMatch) {
                        options.model = ngRepeatMatch[4];
                    }
                }

                // initial animation
                element.addClass('masonry');

                // Wait inside directives to render
                setTimeout(function () {
                    element.masonry(options);

                    element.on("$destroy", function () {
                        element.masonry('destroy')
                    });

                    if (options.model) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.$watchCollection(options.model, function (_new, _old) {
                                if(_new == _old) return;

                                // Wait inside directives to render
                                setTimeout(function () {
                                    element.masonry("reload");
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    };
})
```