# Using isotope with Ng-Repeat Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-isotope

my question is similar to this
[Using Isotope with AngularJS (ng-repeat)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902596/using-isotope-with-angularjs-ng-repeat)

but I cant seem to get mine to work.

i have made a jsfiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/hendhyhutomo/pn937pbq/9/

Everytime i put in the isotope execution line it just stacks up to one.

I have tried the best answer for the solution here by adding this line

```
$http.$watch('doodlesContent',function(){
        $('.doodleswrapper').isotope({
                itemSelector: '.doodles-item'
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hendhyhutomo/pn937pbq/8/

which makes it worse. Maybe I didnt do it correctly. But some help please!

I  also tried angular-isotope. But everytime i run it, the console give me an error that angular-isotope has a missing function.